# Going through the react-router tutorial and rather than using default or null values when loading an empty object, it kicks up an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've been going through [react-router's tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial#setup), and I've been following it to the letter as far as I'm aware. I'm having some issues with the [url params in loaders](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial#url-params-in-loaders)  segment.

The static contact code looks like this

```js
export default function Contact() {
  const contact = {
    first: "Your",
    last: "Name",
    avatar: "https://placekitten.com/g/200/200",
    twitter: "your_handle",
    notes: "Some notes",
    favorite: true,
  }
```

And when it loads, it looks like [this](https://reactrouter.com/_docs/tutorial/09.webp). That works just fine, however, the tutorial then tells me to change that code so that I use data that's loaded in instead. The code now looks like this

```js
import { Form, useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom";
import { getContact } from "../contacts"

export async function loader({ params }) {
  const contact = await getContact(params.contactid);
  return {contact}
}

export default function Contact() {
  const { contact } = useLoaderData();
```

According to the tutorial, it should just load in an empty contact that looks like [this](https://reactrouter.com/_docs/tutorial/10.webp)  but instead, every time I try to open one of the new contacts, it kicks up an error saying

`React Router caught the following error during render TypeError: contact is null`

The actual line of code this error points to is in the return segment of the contact component, which looks like this

```
return (
    <div id="contact">
      <div>
        <img
          key={contact.avatar}
          src={contact.avatar || null}
        />
      </div>

      <div>
        <h1>
          {contact.first || contact.last ? (
            <>
              {contact.first} {contact.last}
            </>
          ) : (
            <i>No Name</i>
          )}{" "}
          <Favorite contact={contact} />
        </h1>

        {contact.twitter && (
          <p>
            <a
              target="_blank"
              href={`https://twitter.com/${contact.twitter}`}
            >
              {contact.twitter}
            </a>
          </p>
        )}

        {contact.notes && <p>{contact.notes}</p>}

        <div>
          <Form action="edit">
            <button type="submit">Edit</button>
          </Form>
          <Form
            method="post"
            action="destroy"
            onSubmit={(event) => {
              if (
                !confirm(
                  "Please confirm you want to delete this record."
                )
              ) {
                event.preventDefault();
              }
            }}
          >
            <button type="submit">Delete</button>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Pretty much anywhere contacts is called gets an error. So, anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here? To my knowledge, I've been following their guide to the letter and it seems like it should be able to handle contacts not having any data, but it's not.

**These are the pieces of my code that are supposed to be working together to render a contact, or at least the pertinent parts**

The router, this is the main file, the only part missing is the part where it's rendered

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import Root, { loader as rootLoader, action as rootAction } from "./routes/root";
import ErrorPage from "./error-page";
import Contact, { loader as contactLoader } from "./routes/contact"

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    loader: rootLoader,
    action: rootAction,
    children: [
      {
        path: "contacts/:contactID",
        element: <Contact />,
        loader: contactLoader
      }
    ]
  }
```

These are the functions in the root file that are called when a new contact is made and when it needs to be displayed

```js
import { Outlet, Link, useLoaderData, Form } from "react-router-dom"
import { getContacts, createContact } from "../contacts"

export async function action() {
  const contact = await createContact();
  console.log("Contact made")
  return {contact}
}

export async function loader(){
  const contacts = await getContacts();
  return {contacts};
}
```

This is the `createContacts` function that gets called when a contact is created, and this is the `getContacts` function

```js
export async function createContact() {
  await fakeNetwork();
  let id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 9);
  let contact = { id, createdAt: Date.now() };
  let contacts = await getContacts();
  contacts.unshift(contact);
  await set(contacts);
  return contact;
}

export async function getContact(id) {
  await fakeNetwork(`contact:${id}`);
  let contacts = await localforage.getItem("contacts");
  let contact = contacts.find(contact => contact.id === id);
  return contact ?? null;
}
```

This is the `contacts.jsx` file where things are currently going wrong. When a new contact is made, it's going to be empty, which I imagine is the source of the problem, but there are checks here to deal with that, or at least there are supposed to be.

```
import { Form, useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom";
import { getContact } from "../contacts"

export async function loader({ params }) {
  const contact = await getContact(params.contactid);
  return { contact }
}

export default function Contact() {
  const { contact } = useLoaderData();

  return (
    <div id="contact">
      <div>
        <img
          // these next two lines are where the errors typically start, 
          // although it seems to extend down to any instance where contact
          // gets called.
          key={contact.avatar}
          src={contact.avatar || null}
        />
      </div>

      <div>
        <h1>
          {contact.first || contact.last ? (
            <>
              {contact.first} {contact.last}
            </>
          ) : (
            <i>No Name</i>
          )}{" "}
          <Favorite contact={contact} />
        </h1>

        {contact.twitter && (
          <p>
            <a
              target="_blank"
              href={`https://twitter.com/${contact.twitter}`}
            >
              {contact.twitter}
            </a>
          </p>
        )}

        {contact.notes && <p>{contact.notes}</p>}

        <div>
          <Form action="edit">
            <button type="submit">Edit</button>
          </Form>
          <Form
            method="post"
            action="destroy"
            onSubmit={(event) => {
              if (
                !confirm(
                  "Please confirm you want to delete this record."
                )
              ) {
                event.preventDefault();
              }
            }}
          >
            <button type="submit">Delete</button>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The React-Router docs are a living document, and sometimes they are incomplete or assume some level of knowledge/familiarity. Can you [edit] the post to include a complete [mcve] of the router, and loader and component code you are trying to use?

Comment: I don't know how well I've cut it down, but there you go, these are the parts that I'm trying to get to work together.

Comment: What does `getContacts` do? Can you include that in your [mcve]?

Comment: It looks through a list of contacts and returns out whichever one has an id that matches the id that gets passed into it. I've added the function in under the createContacts function

Comment: Sorry if this feels like 20 questions, but we don't know what we don't know, so we ask. What does the `contacts` data look like that is pulled in from the `localForage`? I see that if there's not any match found that the loader returns `null`, so the UI should handle that accordingly.

Comment: I'm going to be honest, I don't know. I've never used local forage, and I didn't configure it. The tutorial didn't go into it either so I just took the [premade "contacts" file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ryanflorence/1e7f5d3344c0db4a8394292c157cd305/raw/f7ff21e9ae7ffd55bfaaaf320e09c6a08a8a6611/contacts.js) from the tutorial. I assume it's just returning out null every time since I haven't actually gotten tot he point where you edit or fill in the contact's data, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ok, no worries. I was suspecting that maybe in the data that the `id` keys were not strings whereas the `contactid` route path param would always be a string and the strict equality check would fail to find a match and the loader returns null. The generated `id` values appear to be strings with `let id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 9);`. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of this code that reproduces the issue you see that we could inspect live?

Comment: Sure, and I appreciate the help! I've set up a public [sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nifty-dew-61h7ze?welcome=true). It looks like it's working, although I should note, I've commented out the faulty code (the {contact} = useLoaderData on line 10 of contact.jsx, so right now it looks like it works, but if you comment out the static contact object and re-enable the the other one, it'll break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some subtle, but detrimental, casing issues in the route path params.

The `Contacts` component's route path param is declared as `contactID`.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    loader: rootLoader,
    action: rootAction,
    children: [
      {
        path: "contacts/:contactID", // <-- "contactID"
        element: <Contact />,
        loader: contactLoader,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

The contact loader is referencing a `contactid` path parameter.

```js
export async function loader({ params }) {
  const contact = await getContact(params.contactid); // <-- "contactid"
  return { contact };
}
```

As such, the loader function is unable to find a match and returns `null` to the `Contact` component. An error is thrown in the UI when attempting to access properties of the null reference.

Any valid Javascript identifier will work as the name of the route path parameter, but they should all be in agreement. ***Casing matters in variable names in Javascript.*** The common convention in variable names is to use camelCasing, e.g. `contactId`.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    loader: rootLoader,
    action: rootAction,
    children: [
      {
        path: "contacts/:contactId",
        element: <Contact />,
        loader: contactLoader,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

```js
export async function loader({ params }) {
  const contact = await getContact(params.contactId);
  return { contact };
}
```

Comment: Dear god it's always the simplest problem imaginable isn't it? Thanks for taking the time to look over everything and catch that!